# Defining Broadcast Receiver in simplest way

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I recently created an Application which was an Alarm application .

It used the concept of Broadcast receiver which I understood not very well and right now I am quite confused and have some **Questions** as follows:

1) **How will you describe Broadcast Receiver in layman's term ?**

2) **Do we need to unregister it after registering it,If I don't how will it affect my application ?**

3)**What is the need of using this Broadcast receiver concept ?**

4) Some simple examples if you can.

Comment: What about reading about these on https://developer.android.com ? Or you could search for some tutorials.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Too complex there !

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to your questions:

> 1) How will you describe Broadcast Receiver in layman's term ?

A Broadcast Receiver is something like a listener but it listens for more *global events* on your phone. Like when the phone boots, when you receive a message, when the phone is locked, when your Wifi is turned on/off etc...

> 2) Do we need to unregister it after registering it, If I don't how
>   will it affect my application ?

If you're registering a broadcast receiver in one specific Activity (like a temporary broadcast receiver) then yes you have to unregister it, otherwise you will probably have some errors when switching to another Activity.

> 3)What is the need of using this Broadcast receiver concept ?

The answer 1) may give you some ideas...

> 4) Some simple examples if you can.

There is two ways for registering Broadcast receivers:

1. Programmatically in an Activity, but then it's like temporary and you have to unregister it
2. With your Manifest.xml, it will be permanent and you won't have to unregister it

I'll let you search for yourself these, there are tons of example you can find!

Answer (score 0):

Theory part about Broadcast Receiver - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Registering a receiver -

register it on onResume or onCreate

**registerReceiver(nReceiver, filter);**

Unregistering a receiver  -

unregister it on onDestroy

**unregisterReceiver(nReceiver);**